# Chat ou bate-papo?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, chat, meta-tags

Temos duas tags aqui no Meta que com certeza uma é sinônimo da outra, são as tags:

[chat](/questions/tagged/chat) e [bate-papo](/questions/tagged/bate-papo)

O placar de perguntas que as utiliza está de 7 a 1 para o `chat`, entretanto o texto que temos na UI do nosso site diz `bate-papo`.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pois acham que deveríamos acabar com o estrangeirismo e tornar `chat` ser um sinônimo de `bate-papo` ou vamos seguir o fluxo e tornar `bate-papo` um sinônimo de `chat`?

Comment: Voto seguir o fluxo!

Comment: @renan perae, mas `seguir o fluxo` significaria tornar o `chat` como principal e `bate-papo` como seu sinônimo. Ou eu expliquei errado?

Comment: @bfavaretto o que você entende por `seguir o fluxo`? Acho que eu posso ter me explicado mal, rs.

Comment: Achei melhor criar respostas wiki pro pessoal votar. Fica mais fácil contabilizar a opinião de cada um, e agora acho que fui claro na explicação :) Quem quiser melhorar o texto da resposta fique a vontade, e pode debater nos comentários delas.

Comment: prefiro "chat", já votei lá

Comment: Chat é universal. É como mudar o nome do *mouse* :)

Comment: @papacharlie em Portugal já mudaram o nome do _mouse_ ;-)

Comment: @Math, adotaram qual nome? Aqui nem tentaram rs

Comment: @papacharlie rato mesmo, rs

Comment: É aqui é rato que chamamos e não *mouse*. Já *chat* mantemos o nome em inglês.

Comment: Ia fazer uma piada com os "7 a 1" mas deixa pra lá. Também acho que *chat* cai melhor sim, meu voto está computado.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues hahaha.. que infeliz coincidência :-/ Valeu pelo voto.

Comment: @JorgeB. vocês são mt "do contra", mouse vocês traduzem, chat e t-shirt não?

Comment: @Math traduzir é uma coisa leiaute é outra...

Comment: Se mudar a UI para "chat", voto em chat, caso contrário, não há sentido em tornar bate-papo sinônimo de chat, nem que existam 1 milhão de perguntas com a tag chat.

Comment: @bfavaretto acha que podemos encerrar a votação? `chat` está disparado. Outra pergunta, acha que podemos mudar a UI para `chat` também? Os tuga não entendem `bate-papo`. Seria _só_ mudar no transifex, né não?

Comment: @Math Olhei agora no Transifex, e [são 45 strings contendo "bate-papo"](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40268693?qt=bate-papo). Acho melhor o Gabe opinar sobre isso, pra não corrermos o risco de mudar e depois ter de desmudar... E esta semana o Gabe não conseguirá cuidar disso, então vamos esperar um pouco mais.

Comment: Bate-papo minha vovó que fala, "menino sai do bate-papo"... Já as gatinhas dizem:"Pow, se num entro ontem no chat, fiquei "chat-ada"...Se ligo no trocadilho ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ## chat

É o que foi mais usado para criar as perguntas até agora, portanto é o mais óbvio e o que soa mais natural.

Votando nessa opção você estará optando por tornar `chat` a tag principal, e `bate-papo` será o seu sinônimo.

Comment: Alterei todas as ocorrências de "bate-papo" para "chat", vamos esperar para ver quando isso entra no ar.

Answer (score 8):

> ## bate-papo

Faz muito mais sentido pois está escrito em nossa língua, além de parecer mais sério.

Votando nessa opção você estará optando por tornar `bate-papo` a tag principal, e `chat` será o seu sinônimo.

Comment: Aqui em Portugal "bate-papo" não quer dizer nada.

Comment: Não seria o caso então de mudar a UI de bate papo para chat? :P

Comment: Conversa para chat. Papo aqui e estômago de galinha :D

Comment: Quando criamos um novo bate-papo com alguém, este vem com o nome totalmente em inglês, seria interessante ser "Bate-Papo entre fulano e beltrano"